# Passing data from Django to React

Tags: reactjs, django, frontend, backend

Im trying learn django and react and im doing so by trying to create a web app using spotify api to display top tracks and top artists for users. I have successfully connected to the api and created a view to extract the data I need and have created a template navigating through different time frames etc but i was wondering how i would now use React to build the frontend and how to pass the data to react.

this is my current view to retrieve the users top tracks data:

```
def top_track(request):
    code = request.session.get('spotify_code')
    time_frame = request.GET.get('time_frame', 'short_term')  # Retrieve timeframe parameter from URL, Default to 'short_term'
    limit_frame = request.GET.get('limit_frame', 20)
    if code:
        request.session['spotify_code'] = code
        spotify_auth = SpotifyOAuth(
            client_id=settings.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=settings.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,
            redirect_uri=settings.SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI,
        )
        token_info = spotify_auth.get_access_token(code)
        access_token = token_info['access_token']
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=access_token)

        # Fetch data using the token and the selected time frame
        top_tracks = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=limit_frame, time_range=time_frame)

        # Track info dictionary
        track_info = []
        for track in top_tracks['items']:
            track_id = track['id']
            album = sp.track(track_id)['album']

            album_cover = album['images'][0]['url'] 
        
            artist_name = track['artists'][0]['name']    

            track_info.append({
                'track': track,
                'album_cover': album_cover,
                'artist_name' : artist_name,
            })

        timeframe = " "

        if time_frame == "short_term":
            timeframe = "1 Month"
        elif time_frame == "medium_term":
            timeframe = "6 Months"
        else:
            timeframe = "All Time"


        return render(request, "top_tracks.html", {"top_tracks": track_info, "time_frame": time_frame, "timeframe" : timeframe})
    else:
        return redirect('fail')
```

and this is the template im using:

```
<style>
  ul.track-grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); 
      gap: 20px;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
  }

  ul.track-grid li {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
  }

  ul.track-grid img {
      max-width: 80px;
      height: auto;
  }
</style>


<!-- Display the selected time frame -->
<h1>Your Top Tracks - {{ timeframe }}</h1>

<ul class="track-grid">
    {% for item in top_tracks %}
    <li>
        <img src="{{ item.album_cover }}" alt="Album Cover">
        <figcaption><strong>{{ item.track.name }}</strong> by {{ item.artist_name }}</figcaption>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


<!-- Assign Buttons a Value -->
<button class="time-frame-button" data-time-frame="short_term">1 Month</button>
<button class="time-frame-button" data-time-frame="medium_term">6 Months</button>
<button class="time-frame-button" data-time-frame="long_term">All Time</button>

<button class="limit-frame-button" data-limit-frame=20>Top 20 Tracks</button>
<button class="limit-frame-button" data-limit-frame=50>Top 50 Tracks</button>

<button class="top-artists-button">Top Artists</button>


<!-- Button Clicks -->
<script>
const spotifyCode = "{{ request.session.spotify_code|default:'' }}";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // wait for page to be loaded
  const buttons_time = document.querySelectorAll(".time-frame-button");
  const buttons_limit = document.querySelectorAll(".limit-frame-button");  
  const topArtistsButton = document.querySelector(".top-artists-button");

  buttons_time.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {  // wait for a button to be pressed
      const selectedTimeFrame = event.target.dataset.timeFrame; //retrieve timeframe allocated to button pressed
      const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href); 
      currentUrl.searchParams.set("time_frame", selectedTimeFrame); //set url to selected time frame
      window.location.href = currentUrl; //update page
    }); 
  });

  buttons_limit.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        const selectedLimitFrame = event.target.dataset.limitFrame; //retrieve limitframe allocated to button pressed
        const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href); 
        currentUrl.searchParams.set("limit_frame", selectedLimitFrame); //set url to selected time frame
        window.location.href = currentUrl; //update page
      }); 
    });

  topArtistsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const topArtistUrl = `/top-artists/?code=spotifyCode`;
    window.location.href = topArtistUrl;
  });

});
</script>
```

How would i integrate React into my project and pass the data i retrieve from the spotify api to the react app.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an API with Django rest framework.
You can try quick start here
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#quickstart